# how to use generic this type in this case ? i don't know why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics, types

recently i learned typescript generic. and i used it in certain situations.
but i couldn't.

When using two different interfaces, i wanted it.

for example

i wanna send server request.

```
function fetcher async(){
    return await axios.get(url).then(data=>data.result)
}
```

and server gives me responses
but, they have two different types

```js
// response A
interfase AInterface { 
 name: string;
 age: number;
 address: string
}

// response B
interfase BInterface {
 name: string;
 job : string;
 haveCar: boolean;
}
```

and set return type by using generic

```
function fetcher<T> async():<T>{
    return await axios.get(url).then(data=>data.result)
}
and use function

const result = fetcher<AInterface>()
                or fetcher<BInterface>()
```

result has type AInterface | BInterface

why does result have type AInterface | BInterface  ??

i don't know

i want it has AInterface or BInterface . Not union

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WkMv2N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to type **fetcher**

just use:

```
async function fetcher() {
    const { data } = await axios.get<AInterface>(url)
    return data
}
```

Or:

```
async function fetcher(): Promise<AInterface> {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url)
    return data
}
```